# IOS8 IKEV2 user not disconnecting from windows server 2008 RRAS

Tags: windows-server-2008, vpn

We have severs where all rras protocols are setup, and all are working fine, recently ios8 starts supporting ikev2. we are using configuration file on ios8 for this purpose, connection established successfully with server with config, but the actual issue after disconnection, the user remains in connected state on server, where on ios8 vpn disconnecting fine.